# Are there any official & monitored support forums for Google's Admob?

Tags: admob

According to admob, the "official" support forum for AdMob publishers is here:

http://groups.google.com/group/admob-publisher-discuss

However, questions haven't been answered by anyone from admob in months; it's like a ghost company. Does anyone know why there appears to be no official, monitored, public developer support for AdMob? Is Stackoverflow the only place to get technical questions about AdMob answered now?

Thanks.

Comment: I stopped using AdMob months ago. The CPCs are the worst I've ever had, they NEVER reply to support e-mails, and their new iPhone SDK doesn't even work as I expected.

I'm now using a combination of MobFox, iAds, and JumpTap and I was able to more than double the money I had earned with AdMob alone.

Comment: I tend to agree with your assessment; unfortunately I found JumpTap to be incompatible with Three20, so I couldn't use them; iAds was extremely volatile in its day-to-day revenue and not available on Android; no experience with MobFox. As I've told friends, I consider AdMob to be the worst mobile ad provider, except for all the others.